# How to define protected methods in Raku?

Tags: oop, methods, roles, raku, protected

I have a class and another that inherits from it. There are some methods that I defined in the parent class that I'd like to share privately with the subclass, but not with the world.

How can I achieve something like the protected scope in other programming languages for such methods?

I've thought about introducing a role with private methods, but I'd also need to maintain some private states for use by the methods, and I would need to make both classes `does` the role, but that seems to result in the instance variables (of the role) being duplicated in both classes...

Comment: See https://docs.raku.org/routine/trusts and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braku%5D+trusts

Comment: raiph perhaps one difficult is that the example on the trusts page has errors if you say `class B is A`.  It's entirely due to A have a `.perl` method and B not, so B's uses A's which of course errors because B's foo was never set.  (honestly, we should probably update that doc with a good subclassing trusts example)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two steps do what you want to do.  The first is to have the parent class `trusts` the child class:

```
class Dog { ... }      # forward declaration necessary

class Animal { 
   trusts Dog;         # Dog now has access to private methods
   method !secret { 
     return 42
   }
}

class Dog is Animal {
   method tell-secret { ... }
}
```

Now, let's have the Dog reveal Animal's secret.  You might think that it's simple

```
method tell-secret { 
  say self!secret
}
```

But that doesn't work.  While calling public methods will follow standard MRO to determine the one that's called, with private ones we must be explicit.  In this case, `self!secret` would refer to a `method !secret` directly belonging to `Dog`.  To refer to `Animal`'s secret method, we make it explicit:

```
method tell-secret { 
  say self!Animal::secret
}
```

And now Dog can spill the beans, so to speak.

One thing you'll notice is that once a class trusts another, it opens itself up entirely.  There's no way to limit trust to individual methods.